# Android - SpannableString set Images

Tags: java, android

I have an `ArrayList` of drawable resource and I want to add that icon to my string on the text start

example 
this is my text

> hello world

now I want to add multi-image or icon at the start of text so it will be like this

> emoji emoji emoji emoji hello world

I just try this

```
SpannableString spannableString = new SpannableString("hello world");

 for(int i =0;i < resource.size(); i++){
  Drawable drawable = getDrawable(context,resource.get(i),ContextCompat.getColor(context,R.color.gray));
            drawable.setBounds(0, 0, 22, 22);
            ImageSpan span1 = new ImageSpan(drawable);
            spannableString.setSpan(span1, i, i+1, Spanned.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

 }
```

and this the getDrawable function  its only for change resource color

```
  private static Drawable getDrawable(Context context, int resource, int color){
        Drawable outgoing = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, resource);
        ColorFilter filter = new LightingColorFilter(color, color);
        outgoing.setColorFilter(filter);
        return outgoing;
    }
```

but I get an error

> java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: setSpan (16 ... 17) ends beyond length 16

its seems my code insert emoji on the string according to the start and end position but what I want its insert at the start of the text

> {emoji emoji emoji emoji} my text here

Answer (score 1):

you can use this code , it should work for you

```
Drawable image = 
context.getResources().getDrawable(imageResId[position]);
image.setBounds(0, 0, image.getIntrinsicWidth(), 
image.getIntrinsicHeight());
SpannableString sb = new SpannableString(" ");
ImageSpan imageSpan = new ImageSpan(image, ImageSpan.ALIGN_BOTTOM);
sb.setSpan(imageSpan, 0, 1, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

Another Solution :-

```
String html="";
for (int i = 0; i < emojilist.length-1; i++) { 
  html += "<img src ='"+ emojilist[i] +"'/>";
} 

Spanned cs = Html.fromHtml(html, imageGetter, null); 
textviewobject.setText(cs);
```

Comment: and where is my text ?

Comment: SpannableString sb = new SpannableString(" --your text comes here ");

Comment: i do that but i want to add multi emoji on the start of this text 
`hello world` must be like this
` hello world`

Comment: use second solution from the answer.